# Is it possible to only install keosd on ubuntu?

Tags: transactions, wallet, signin

I need a solution for signing transactions sent with HTTP API (RPC) from a .Net webserver. EOSjs works fine for signing transactions in the browser - but some transactions must be sent from the server. My plan is to install keosd on a minimal cloud service Ubuntu installation - just for using wallet functions and signing transactions. Is it possible? Or do I have to use the full installation with eosio_build.sh?

Comment: There are no official docs that I'm aware of for just installing keosd, so you'd likely need to get creative.  If there were docs on this, they would be here: https://developers.eos.io/  If you're concerned about the 7GB build requirement, then see my post on building with down to 4GB of RAM.

Answer (score 2):

What I did to get eos working on an AWS free tier instance was I temporarily opened up a large ubuntu instance with enough RAM to install it, and I ran the install. Once it was done you can scp the eos/build directory to a free tier AWS instance and that's all you need to run nodeos/keosd/cleos.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run `keosd` executable file alone in a system. It worked for me in local system without building the whole EOSIO. Upload the the executable file to the cloud.

Then run in CLI,

```
cd <directiory>

./keosd
```

Answer (score 0):

You no longer need to compile the executables, Block.one now publishes binaries for many platforms, including Ubuntu, with each release.  Check the assets listed at the end of each release.  For example, see https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v1.7.1 which has the following assets:

```
eosio-1.7.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm 15.1 MB
eosio-1.7.1-1.fc27.x86_64.rpm 14.9 MB
eosio-1.7.1.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz 18.5 MB
eosio-1.7.1.mojave.bottle.tar.gz 18.5 MB
eosio_1.7.1-1-ubuntu-16.04_amd64.deb 14.3 MB
eosio_1.7.1-1-ubuntu-18.04_amd64.deb 14.7 MB
Source code (zip)   Source code (tar.gz)
```